# Question mark before function/object literal mean

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Hi in the following function, what dos the question mark mean:

```
  static getCurrentAccessToken(callback: (token: ?FBSDKAccessToken) => void) {
    FBSDKAccessTokenInterface.getCurrentAccessToken((tokenDict) => {
      callback(tokenDict ? new FBSDKAccessToken(tokenDict) : null);
    });
  }
```

I dont understand this part: `(token: ?FBSDKAccessToken)`

And yes, this is javascript ES6. Have a look [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/0d60d76137de8cdb5b1d493271c22f2c7e349520/react-native-fbsdkcore/js/FBSDKAccessToken.ios.js).
Update: this is flow handling javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Doesn't look like JavaScript to me

Comment: That's not JavaScript. Maybe TypeScript? *Edit:* Well, the TypeScript transpiler *seems* to say it's syntactically valid (inside a class), so could be TypeScript.

Comment: Not a duplicate -- not about the ternary operator at all

Comment: http://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html#_

Comment: @Jesse This is not duplicate. mind the terms `a ? b : c` (your link) and the ops question `token: ?FBAccessToken` - thats something different!

Comment: @AxelAmthor - Read his code again, `tokenDict ? new FBSDKAccessToken(tokenDict) : null` literally means "is there a tokenDict? Yes? FBSDKAccessToken(tokenDict), no? NULL'

Comment: who cares what language it is, it's called a "ternary operator" in all of them... and that's not javascript, i don't care what anyone says, if it doesn't even parse in V8, it ain't JS AFAIC...

Comment: @Jesse don't insist, you're wrong: `static getCurrentAccessToken(` **callback: (token: ?FBSDKAccessToken)** `=> void) {`

Comment: Thanks. That was edited in there way after I flagged it and it auto added my comment when flagging. See his edit history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a nullable type hint for an object variable in flow, as @epascarello already found out.

And as JavaScript doesn't have type hints  but even a typeless `null`, that isn't Javascript at all.